# Different typeconverters for different custom object entity in room database

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, android-database

Here i need to store **multiple custom entities in same table** in room database. This things are working in single typeconverter but when it comes in the case of multiple typeconverters then it is throwing error.

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.TypeConverter
import androidx.room.TypeConverters
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import java.lang.reflect.Type


@Entity(tableName = "tbl_finalOrder")
@TypeConverters(ItemEntityConverter::class)
data class FinalOrdersEntity (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,

     val itemEntity: ItemEntity?,
   // val itemEntity: String? = null,
    var quantity: String?=null,
    var unitName: String?=null,
    var unitId: Int?=null,
    var statusOfScheme: Boolean?=null,

    @TypeConverters(SchemeDetailConverter::class)
    var listOfScheme: List<SchemeDetailEntity>?=null,
  
    val child_items: String?=null,
    val selectedOffer:String? = null,
    var offer:String?=null
)






class ItemEntityConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToItemEntity(string: String?): ItemEntity  = Gson().fromJson(string,ItemEntity::class.java)

    @TypeConverter
    fun itemEntityToString(list: ItemEntity?): String =Gson().toJson(list)
}


class SchemeDetailConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToSchemeDetailEntity(json: String?): List<SchemeDetailEntity> {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<SchemeDetailEntity?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson<List<SchemeDetailEntity>>(json, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun schemeDetailEntityToString(list: List<SchemeDetailEntity?>?): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<SchemeDetailEntity?>?>() {}.type
        return gson.toJson(list, type)
    }
}
```

**When i run this then it ask to make typeconverter class for listOfScheme.However, there is one already for it.**

> error
> FinalOrdersEntity.java:22: error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
> private java.util.List<com.myproject.database.entities.SchemeDetailEntity> listOfScheme;

Can you tell me where and what i am missing here. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score -1):

```
data class FinalOrdersEntity (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id:Int,
@TypeConverters(ItemEntityConverter::class)
     val itemEntity: ItemEntity?,
   // val itemEntity: String? = null,
    var quantity: String?=null,
    var unitName: String?=null,
    var unitId: Int?=null,
    var statusOfScheme: Boolean?=null,

    @TypeConverters(SchemeDetailConverter::class)
    var listOfScheme: List<SchemeDetailEntity>?=null,
  
    val child_items: String?=null,
    val selectedOffer:String? = null,
    var offer:String?=null
)
```

Check if the SchemeDetailEntity has any variable with class as the type,if yes then you should add the type converter class for that too